# Factor of polynomial ring

Tags: abstract-algebra, polynomials, ring-theory

> What do the elements of i.e. $\mathbb Z[X]/(5X-1)$ look like?

In a more general context: If $p\in R[X]$ is monic and of degree $d$, then I can "understand" that $R[X]/(p)=\{\overline{a_{d-1}X^{d-1}+\dots+a_1X+a_0}\mid a_0,\dots,a_{d-1}\in R\}$ because we basically just divide all polynomials by $p$. I'm sure though that in general that is not correct and depends on the roots of p. And in the example above we have that i.e. $X$ is not divisible by the non-monic $5X-1$, so the given ring cannot be isomorphic to $\mathbb Z$? That's where I'm confused. If I can apply my very limited knowledge of field theory it should be isomorphic to $\mathbb Z[1/5]$ as a 2-dimensional $\mathbb Z$-module?

Comment: Note that $\mathbb{Z}\left[\frac{1}{5}\right]$ is a valid ring (it is the localization of the monoid $\left\{5^{i}:i\in\mathbb{N}\cup\left\{0\right\}\right\}$ in $\mathbb{Z}$), and you can look for a ring isomorphism - not just a module one.

Comment: Yes, I should rephrase my question: When is  $R[X]/(p)=\{\overline{a_{d-1}X^{d-1}+\dots+a_1X+a_0}\mid a_0,\dots,a_{d-1}\in R\}$?

Comment: Always, where the over bar denotes modulu the ideal $\left<p\right>$.

Comment: But then we'd have $\mathbb Z[X]/(5X-1)=\mathbb Z$ since $d=1$, where is my error in thoughts?

Comment: Why is that the consequence? You have said yourself that $\bar{X}\neq\bar{n}$ for any $n\in\mathbb{Z}$.

Comment: I've edited the answer: The problem probably is within the degree $d$.

Comment: Why is $d=1$? An element in $R\left[X\right]$ is of finite degree, meaning that $d\in\mathbb{N}$.

Comment: $d=\deg(5X-1)=1$, now I'm getting kind of lost.

Comment: Where did you read this? This is incorrect.

Comment: The degree of a polynomial $\sum_i a_i X^i$ is defined by $\text{max} \{i\in\mathbb N\mid a_i\neq 0\}$. What would you say is the degree of $5X-1$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$\mathbb{Z}[X](5X - 1) \cong \mathbb{Z}[1/5]$ since the image of $X$ is a multiplicative inverse of $5$.  Every element $\mathbb{Z}[1/5]$ is of the form $a/5^e$ where $a$ and $e$ are integers.

However, $\mathbb{Z}[1/5]$ is not a $2$-dimensional (really you should say rank $2$) $\mathbb{Z}$-module.  First, it's not finitely generated: any finite $\mathbb{Z}$-linear combination of elements of the form $a/5^e$ will have a bounded denominator, and $\mathbb{Z}[1/5]$ contains elements with denominators that are arbitrarily large powers of $5$.  Second, it's not a free $\mathbb{Z}$-module, since there will be a linear relation among any set of generators.  Given any two elements $a_1/5^{e_1}, a_2/5^{e_2} \in \mathbb{Z}[1/5]$, we have
$$
a_2 5^{e_1} \cdot \frac{a_1}{5^{e_1}} - a_1 5^{e_2} \frac{a_2}{5^{e_2}} = 0 \, .
$$

Given a commutative ring $R$, the extension $R[\alpha]$ is finitely generated as a $R$-module iff $\alpha$ is [integral](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integral_element#Equivalent_definitions) over $R$, i.e., if $\alpha$ is a root of a monic polynomial with coefficients in $R$.  If $\alpha$ satisfies monic a degree $d$ polynomial in $R[X]$, then $\{1, \alpha, \ldots, \alpha^{d-1}\}$ is a basis for $R[\alpha]$ as an $R$-module, so
$$
R[\alpha] \cong R \oplus R \alpha \oplus \cdots \oplus R \alpha^{d-1} \, .
$$

Comment: I see, thanks!
Although by discussing (see above) this problem I now have realized that my basic problem is somewhere else (also see above) and I would be glad if you could clarify this as well.

Comment: I added a remark about integral extensions.  Does that answer your question?

Comment: Not yet. I'm wondering in which situation I can write the elements of $R/(p)$ in the form $a_{d-1}X^{d-1}+\dots+a_1X+a_0$ where $d=\deg(p)$.

Comment: If $p$ is irreducible, then $R/(p) \cong R[\alpha]$ where $\alpha$ is a root of $p$.  You can write the elements in the form you want iff $R/(p)$ is a free $R$-module of finite rank (if you assume such an expression is unique), which is true iff $p$ is monic.

Comment: Perfect! Thanks again.

Answer (score 2):

I'll answer your comment question. You have said that $d=\deg\left(5X-1\right)=1$. In other words, you are thinking that if you divide by an ideal generated by a first degree polynomial - then the elements of the quotient ring must be of lower degree, *i.e.* integers in your case. By saying this you're unintentionally assuming that $\mathbb{Z}\left[X\right]$ is an **Euclidean domain** (=you can divide with reminder), which is false. You can't divide polynomials in $\mathbb{Z}\left[X\right]$ (for example, try to divide $X$ by $2X$. You'll see it fails. An example that's more relevant to your case is dividing $X$ by $5X-1$, which also doesn't work). If you **did** have an Euclidean domain, say $\mathbb{Q}\left[X\right]$, then you could divide $p(X)\in\mathbb{Q}\left[X\right]$ by $5X-1\in\mathbb{Q}\left[X\right]$

$$p(X)=q(X)(5X+1)-r(X)$$

$$\overline{p(X)}=\overline{r(X)}$$

where $\deg r\leq\deg(5X-1)=1\Longrightarrow r\in\mathbb{Q}$. This proves that

$$\mathbb{Q}\left[X\right]/\left<5X-1\right>\cong\mathbb{Q}$$

but as I've already stated, your case is different.

Comment: It's true that I was thinking about dividing polynomials when making that $R/(p)=\dots$-statement which I now see is a false perception. That has nothing to do though with my remark about the degree of $5X-1$. Thanks anyway, you've helped me discover a lot of errors in my thinking!

Comment: @Buh You're welcome. As for your remark, the degree was correct of course. I meant to the statement that $d=\deg(5X-1)$ (where $d$ is the same as the one appears in your expression for the quotient ring), not that $\deg(5X-1)=1$.